# How can I evaluate if a rescue case was reached?

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am running an exception handler, and then in another file want to evaluate whether or not the exception handler was ran successfully, or if the rescue case ran.

I'm pretty new to Ruby, and I'm not sure how to evaluate what actually happened in my exception handler, and how to store the results (or if that's even possible). Here's how the code looks.

***File one - which runs an API call***

```
begin
  HTTParty.get(BASE_URL + url)
rescue
  Hash['message' => 'There was an error connecting with the API, contact support if error persists.']
end
```

***File two - which analyzes whether or not the API call was succesful***

```
response = call_to_api #api call is ran in file one

if response == #I'm not sure what to put here, but it needs to check if the exception handler didn't trip the rescue
  success
else
  error
end
```

Comment: As an aside, `Hash['message' => 'There was...']` isn't the right way to create a Hash. The [`Hash[]` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) returns a new Hash with the keys and values of the object given as its argument. The argument you're giving is already a Hash (with key `'message'` and value `'There was...'`), and what you're getting back is a copy of it. You should just use a Hash literal instead: `{ 'message' => 'There was...' }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with that using different approaches, look at those two examples:

```
# You can catch the error just to handle it and bypass to the caller
# In this case, the caller will need to rescue your custom error
# Example 1
def my_method
  begin
    ...
  rescue
    raise MyCustomError
  end
end

begin
  my_method
rescue MyCustomError => err
  ...
end

# You can provide the error through a block
# Example 2
def my_method
  begin
    yield MyApi.call
  rescue
    yield :fail, { message: 'error' }
  end
end

my_method do |result, error|
  ...
end
```

Consider not to handle generic errors in rescue but actually catch specific ones and deal with them, if you put only `rescue` you are assuming that whatever error will be handled in a single way in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the `HttParty` gem [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), You can do

```
# Use the class methods to get down to business quickly
response = HTTParty.get('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow')

puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

So, in your call api function, it depends on what the API returns

```
response = call_to_api #api call is ran in file one

if response.code == 200 or response.message == "OK"
  success
else
  error
end
```